# Spring '21 Aura component problem at install time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, package-install, lightning-quickaction

We have a problem with some **unchanged code** that will now not install in Spring '21. The problem might relate to the naming of a base component that we called "action":

```
<aura:component
    extensible="true"
    abstract="true"  
    implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,..." 
    controller="Actions"
    >
```

that is extended like this:

```
<aura:component extends="c:action">
```

that I can imagine might cause a name clash but of course the problem could be something else entirely. The error reported includes this:

> You can’t remove the ‘force:lightningQuickAction’ interface

If you have experienced this problem and have a workaround, do share that. Unfortunately we are particularly constrained because we are hitting the problem in a patch version and that means only limited changes can be made.

(We have a Case created but there has been no progress with that for the last several weeks. If a solution comes through that route, I will post here.)

Comment: Salesforce have now recognised this and listed it as a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JjxFQAS).

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce has recognised that as a known issue and currently there is no suggested workaround.

> Interface validation is failing incorrectly on package install when a
> lightning component that extends another lightning component which
> implements the required quick action interfaces
> (force:lightningQuickAction / force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader)

Source: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JjxFQAS

Above is the link to check the status, please **check** the "**This issue affects me**" checkbox. Hopefully it will help to have this issue fixed soon.

Comment: This issue has been fixed by Salesforce.